# Not found method emulation via proxy

Tags: javascript

In past, JS had Object.prototype.__ noSuchMethod __ for handling nonexistent methods, so you was able to use methods as messages according to OOP.

Unfortunatelly, it's deprecated now. Replacement is Proxy object. But apply handler catch calls only on functions, not objects, so you can't catch nonexistent methods.

You can use get handler, but you don't know if you should return some function, or value, or nothing and just do something. You haven't context of name access.

So, any ideas how to handle nonexistent methods without explicit checking?

Comment: That was only supported in Firefox

Comment: You do get the name of the property from the get handler. You should post an example of what you have tried

Comment: Juan Mendes, please read my post properly. I can get the name via get, but I don't know if someone tried to access property or call method. I'm missing context of name access.

Comment: But you know the name of the methods you would like to override, if the property name is one that you to to be a function, you return the implementation.

Comment: Well, If I follow some naming convention, I'm able to determine if user tryed to acces property or call method. Unfortunatelly it's unelegant, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the exact behavior of `Object.prototype.__ noSuchMethod __` but you can get pretty close. You would know which properties you want override, so something like the following should work.

Without a simple example of how you are using it, it's hard to suggest something more meaningful. That is, questions should always show code.

```js
var obj = {
  b: 1,
  c: 2
};

var proxy = new Proxy(obj, {
  get: function(target, property, receiver) {
    if (property == 'addBC') {
        return function() {
          return target.b + target.c;
        }
    }
    
    return target[property];
  }
})


console.log('proxy.addBC() => ' , proxy.addBC()); // 3

console.log(proxy.b); // 1 

console.log(proxy.noexist); // undefined

try {
  console.log(proxy.noexist());
} catch(e) { 
  console.log('error running no exist function')
}
```

Comment: I haven't any JS system build on "messaging", so I can't show you code. This question was only informative, because sometimes, proxy object is best way to do something in dynamic OOP language.